# Bash: function to start an app in a background?

Tags: bash, function

The following function:

```
esb () { emacs -f server-start $@ &; }
```

gives an error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Is there a way to start an app in a background in Bash?

**Edit**:

So the solution is:

```
esb () { emacs -f server-start "$@" & }
```

Comment: highly recommend you use `"$@"` to protect any arguments with spaces.

Comment: @glenn jackman: but suppose I'll open several files? If I quote $@ emacs would think I've given him a single file name. While with no quotes one can manually escape all spaces.

Comment: that's incorrect. `"$@"` is magical in that it expands to exactly the list of parameters. `"$*"` will become a single word. Both unquoted `$@` and `$*` are subject to word splitting. Further discussion [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_arg_in_.24.2A) and documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

Comment: @glenn jackman: Wow I never knew that. I'll change to "$@".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `&` and `;` are command separators. Use only one; you do not get super bash scripting powers by combining them.